# SyncResultReceiver$TimeoutException crashing Android a lot

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I've disabled all autofill with View.AUTOFILL_TYPE_NONE

```
com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver$TimeoutException: 
  at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.waitResult (SyncResultReceiver.java:60)
  at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.getIntResult (SyncResultReceiver.java:68)
  at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked (AutofillManager.java:1831)
  at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEnteredLocked (AutofillManager.java:956)
  at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered (AutofillManager.java:940)
  at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered (AutofillManager.java:897)
  at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded (View.java:7972)
  at android.view.View.onFocusChanged (View.java:7934)
  at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged (TextView.java:10801)
  at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal (View.java:7597)
  at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch (View.java:12962)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:12936)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:12903)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus (View.java:12845)
  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent (View.java:15336)
```

I am not sure what is wrong.

It only happens to Android 10 devices.

This happens when I click on an EditText the app crashes and restarts.

Comment: Can you add more info about the error log? The view it's occuring in? The action taking place?

Comment: This happens when I click on an EditText the app crashes and restarts.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved my problem with similar crash on click on edittext, by rename of variable named "userId"
I'm still not shure why this magic works, but try to rename such variables with common names

Comment: I think you should be more specific about what you mean with "common names".